# How to declare the TypeScript Type for a Java Map of Map of Sets?

Tags: java, arrays, json, typescript, dictionary

In Java I have something like this:

```
public class MyMatrix implements Map<Long, Map<Long, Set<MyObject>>> {...}
```

What I would like to do is to declare the corresponding type of this Map in TypeScript.

The corresponding JSON is:

```
{
   "1":{
      "1":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
   },
   "2":{
      "1":[{"id":2},{"id":3}]
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to access it using associative array notation, e.g. `myArray[1][1] should return [{"id":1},{"id":2}]`

I have tried using something like this

```
var myMatrix: Array<Array<Array<MyObjec>>>;
```

but without luck.

When trying the following code:

```
for (const x in Object.keys(this.myMatrix)) {
  for (const y in Object.keys(this.myMatrix[x])) {
  }
}
```

I get the following error on the second for loop:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
```

Hopefully I found a little **HINT**: the reason of this error seems to be that in the first loop `Object.keys` is starting from `'0'` instead of `'1'` and this is even stranger to me.

Comment: Since you are using typescript, why not using ES6 `Map` and `Set`? Define your variable like this: `let myMatrix: Map<number, Map<number, Set<any>>>;`

Answer (score 1):

HugoTeixeira's type looks right to me.  This code:

```
for (const x in Object.keys(this.myMatrix)) {
  for (const y in Object.keys(this.myMatrix[x])) {
  }
}
```

should be:

```
for (const x of Object.keys(this.myMatrix)) {
//           ^^
  for (const y of Object.keys(this.myMatrix[x])) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create one type for each layer, like this:

```
interface Column { 
    id: number;
}

interface Row { 
    [key: number]: Array<Column>;
}

class Matrix {
    [key: number]: Row;
}
```

Then you can create a Matrix like this:

```
const myMatrix: Matrix = {  
    "1":{
        "1":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
    },
    "2":{
        "1":[{"id":2},{"id":3}]
    }
};
```

From the Typescript code, you can access the Matrix using the associative array notation, as you wanted:

```
const arr = myMatrix[1][1];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

This prints:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can declare Maps in Typescript, so you can try using something like below and then iterate it using foreach.

```
var dataMap = new Map<number, Map<number,Array<Obj>>>();
```